# Authentication steps when deploying to pipelines

Tags: authentication

I'd be interested in hearing some feedback on this

We have an integration tool (i.e Jenkins) that's used to run and deploy pipelines. Elsewhere there are other tools like atlassian etc.

We're going to implement SSO with MFA but I have a question:

When a person is going to run a deployment with a target of a production environment,

- should there be an extra authentication step (otp, short lived
  credential) - is that even possible? Or
- should there be no extra step (other than some business change approval mechanism) as these guys have already authenticated, got an identity from a trusted provider and are in a group with privileges to do this.

Comment: "as these guys have already authenticated, got an identity from a trusted provider and are in a group with privileges to do this." what else do they need to do to start a deployment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the possible consequences of misusing of deployment permissions.

If user with deployment permission has left his computer for a few minutes unlocked, somebody can use it to deploy some bad (e.g. with known critical bugs) or even malicious application revision. If this  can cause a big money loss for your company, e.g. improper deployment activates Christmas discounts in March, then it may make sense to request authentication once again. If the potential problems are not critical, e.g. your web site provides whether information for normal users, then the current authentication can be sufficient and new authentication would give no essential benefits.